# User marked question as duplicate when in fact it is not

Tags: support, status-completed

A user marked my question

[ANSI C / rand() % 7 first value is always 3 [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458136/ansi-c-rand-7-first-value-is-always-3)

as a duplicate of

[Why do I always get the same sequence of random numbers with rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand)

When in fact my question though may seem related to the other is not. I feel the user just assumed it was a duplicate with out reading the content to include the code. How can I get my question unmarked as a duplicate.

Comment: Looks like a dupe to me. The question has a satisfactory answer; what would be the point of reopening it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not quite. The dupe is not seeding at all. Whereas this question is seeding on every iteration. I've duped it to a different question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then you fail to read it as well. He referenced a post where the question is regarding to same sequence of random numbers with default seed. I'm asking why does using a different seed every second with time() and then moding it with 7 always return 3. I'm curious as to if anyone know mores specifics about the algorithms involved in srand(), rand(), and time() that may be able to explain this unique phenomenon of rand() % 7

Comment: What is the compelling reason you are providing for reopening an asked and answered question?

Comment: It hasn't been asked or answered

Comment: Really?  [This answer got 7 upvotes.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24458170/102937).  Are you saying it is incorrect? Ricky essentially [provided the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24458183/102937).

Comment: @Mysticial your dupe question still doesn't have anything to do with my question. I purposefully used srand() within the loop. The thing is that if you % 7 u always get 3 in this loop but if you use any other C such that !(7|C) then you will get a better sequence of initial values

Comment: I guess you'd better edit your original question to make it clear what, specifically you're asking.

Comment: I'm marking this completed.  If you need further help, take it up the chain of command.

Comment: @ThomasWatters Okay. I had to re-read your question about 5 times before I figured out what the actual question is. In that case, I agree it's not a duplicate. But the wording was enough to fool me and lots of other people. The system won't let me reopen twice so it'll have to be someone else.

Comment: Well i'm not an english major I apologize I tried to use as much clear wording as i could

Comment: I suggest getting rid of the loop and doing a bunch of sequential calls to `rseed(0); rand(); rseed(1); rand(); rseed(2); rand();`. That will definitively distinguish it from both dupes it was closed as.

Comment: @gnati had read that and edited my post like that post said but I felt like noone was viewing my OP because it was marked as a dupe, so I brought it here.

Comment: @Thomas: editing a closed post will push it into the reopen queue automatically. Your post will then be reviewed in the context of your change. Make it count!

Comment: @Thomas: ah, Robert already reopened it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could write the same code to show that time is changing like:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         time_t tt = time(NULL);
         srand(tt);
         printf("r: %d tt: %d\n", rand() % 7, tt);

         sleep(1);
    }
}
```

at which point you could rewrite, with the sleep removed:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    time_t tt = time(NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         srand(tt + i); // on purpose look at strange results
         printf("r: %d tt: %d\n", rand() % 7, tt+i);
    }
}
```

At which point you could completely rewrite the question like:

> I have noticed the after Seeding the RNG on my system (name OS
>   version, compiler) that the first result when moduled with 7 is 3.
>
> Here's some code show this....

At which point you then ask something interest,

why does this happen? or
does anybody else see this? or
this impact is important bacause the world banking system does this, and you can also force a re-seed, thus the world bank system is hack-able.

but as it stands your question feels like *when I put values into the formula* `f(x) = 0*x + C` *I have found the I get 'C' all the time*.

Comment: I completely agree with how you rephrased the question but to be honest I didn't have a clue really what was causing the issue, but I tried to make it clear that I wasn't having issues generating different random numbers or not using stand() correctly, I trouble shot it the best way I knew how but it got marked as a dupe almost immediately and I just felt that was uncalled for. I appreciate you trying to help me figure this out tho

Comment: The dupe part I'm cool with. But thought it might more sense to discuss you post in meta section verse the main site.